# How to transparently query local or remote data in Jena

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I would like to have code that query RDF data without knowing if the data is local (loaded from a file) or remote (in a SPARQL endpoint).
In Jena it seems there are two different methods for this, I need to do the following to query a endpoint :

```
QueryExecution qExec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(endpointURL, sparqlQuery);
```

and the following to query a Model/Dataset :

```
QueryExecution qExec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(sparqlQuery, dataset);
```

How can I write code that doesn't have have to worry whether the data is local or remote ? I am thinking of something similar to OpenRDF Sesame Repository abstraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything in Jena for this at the moment, there is an unpublished *jena-client* experimental module which may be of interest to you but you'll have to build it yourself from source if you want to try it.

You can view it in your browser at https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jena/Experimental/jena-client/

Or to check it out:

```
svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jena/Experimental/jena-client jena-client
```

Comment: Bad news nothing exists in Jena at the moment, good news there is at least some experimental stuff :-) jena-client what I was looking for, thanks.